# Redshift query to delete 6 month old data

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a redshift table where scannable_id_latest_update_timestamp is the column containing epoch timestamp. I'm trying to run a query which returns all the rows  where scannable_id_latest_update_timestamp is older than 6 months

Tried below query

```
select *
from scannable_id_pin_mappings
where date_cmp(dateadd(month,6,current_date), timestamp 'epoch' +
               scannable_id_latest_update_timestamp * interval '1 second') = -1;
```

Gettng exception

> Invalid operation: function date_cmp(timestamp without time zone,
>   timestamp without time zone) does not exist;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `scannable_id_latest_update_timestamp` is an epoch value you can compare them directly without a function by converting the other timestamp to an epoch.

```
SELECT EXTRACT( EPOCH FROM DATEADD( month , -6 , current_date ) ) ;
--  date_part
-- ------------
--  1542931200

SELECT *
FROM scannable_id_pin_mappings
WHERE scannable_id_latest_update_timestamp 
    < EXTRACT( EPOCH FROM DATEADD( month , -6 , current_date ) ) ;
```